# How to inject Document in service?

Tags: typescript, angular

I have an Angular 2 application. For mocking the  `Document` object in tests, I'd like to inject it to the service like:

```
import { Document } from '??' 

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(document: Document) {}
}
```

The `Title` service of Angular [uses the internal `getDOM()` method](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/platform-browser/src/browser/title.ts).

Is there any simple way to inject the `Document` to the service? Also, how should I reference it in the `providers` array?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

This has been supported by Angular for a while.

You can use the [`DOCUMENT`](https://angular.io/api/common/DOCUMENT) constant provided by the `@angular/common` package.

Description of the `DOCUMENT` constant (taken from the [API documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/DOCUMENT)):

> A DI Token representing the main rendering context. In a browser, this is the DOM Document.

An example is as shown below:

#### my-service.service.ts:

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}
}
```

#### my-service.service.spec.ts

```
import { provide } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

import { MyService } from './my-service';

class MockDocument {}

describe('MyService', () => {
  beforeEachProviders(() => ([
    provide(DOCUMENT, { useClass: MockDocument }),
    MyService
  ]));

  ...
});
```

Comment: And in the real implementation, we should provide the actual document instance, e.g.,
`declare const document: Document;` and then `bootstrap(provide(Document, { useValue: document }));`

Comment: Why would that be necessary?

Comment: Since failing to do that gives me exception: `ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Document!`. Unless you can give an example where this is not necessary?

Comment: I will accept the answer, if you can give a working example of both use cases: production and tests.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer it looks like [DOCUMENT is deprecated](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DOCUMENT). Any idea how to do this once it's gone? For example, how would I set the favicon dynamically?

Comment: You can alwasy use plain JS/TS `document.title = 'foo';` but I guess https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2 is the replacement (not tried myself yet)

Comment: @adamdport - import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common'; instead of '@angular/platform-browser'

Comment: This answer is confusing (it seems all over the place - where is bootstrap(provide.. supposed to be called?). Is it out of date? Is there an equivalent answer that actually shows what is supposed to go where? Note that I don't need to mock anything: I'm attempting to inject DOCUMENT for an app for production. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50920734/cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-when-consuming-injectable-from-a-package

Comment: I updated my answer (not sure about the test part, haven't used Angular since quite some time)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks, however where does myDocumentImpl come from?

Comment: PS: I'm not sure this method is even going to resolve my issue - it might be a bug?

Comment: @DaveNottage I updated again. I'm somewhat out of practice in Angular.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Still doesn't help in my scenario

Comment: As type, you can use `HTMLDocument` instead of `any`:
`@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: HTMLDocument`

Comment: Not sure if this works for server-side rendering. The injected document might be of a different type. Besides that, thanks for the update.

Comment: Does anyone know what this is on the server? Can I use DOCUMENT.getElementById for instance?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't (never tried SSR). There is no document on the server. If you inject it you get an empty facade.

Comment: This approach is the same way official material components access global document object as well: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/2b1d84e2bc1d7295e53a753211e99a0e73110b45/src/cdk/drag-drop/drag-drop-registry.ts#L64

Answer (score 36):

I'm unable to comment directly on adamdport's question (not yet 50 rep points), but here it is as stated in the angular docs.

> Blockquote
>   @GünterZöchbauer it looks like DOCUMENT is deprecated. Any idea how to do this once it's gone? For example, how would I set the favicon dynamically?

Instead of importing from platform browser like so:

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Import it from angular common:

```
import {DOCUMENT} from '@angular/common';
```

Answer (score 11):

in addition to @Günter Zöchbauer's answer.

Angular define DOCUMENT as an InjectionToken

```
export const DOCUMENT = new InjectionToken<Document>('DocumentToken');
```

[dom_tokens.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/bebedfed24d6fbfa492e97f071e1d1b41e411280/packages/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_tokens.ts#L19)

And inject it with document in [browser.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/bebedfed24d6fbfa492e97f071e1d1b41e411280/packages/platform-browser/src/browser.ts#L33)

```
{provide: DOCUMENT, useFactory: _document, deps: []}


export function _document(): any {
  return document;
}
```

Therefore, when we use it, we just need to inject `@Inject(DOCUMENT)`

or use the token directly in `deps:[DOCUMENT]`

Comment: This works in AOT (production) when you need the actual document. It prevents "ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically"

Comment: Doesn't work for me in AOT, at least for Angular 6. I'm receiving the error "Can't resolve all parameters for..". See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50920734/cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-when-consuming-injectable-from-a-package

Comment: does this resolve correctly if the angular app is rendered in a non-browser?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) {}
}
```

It's the ": Document" that's causing the problem.

Comment: i too getting this same isues, do you have solution for this?