# How to use document.write in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

In my normal HTML page I am having a simple 4 line code shown below:

```
<script>
var getData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("templateType"));
document.write(getData.template_code); // in angular its wriiten as getData["template_code"]
console.log(getData.template_code);
document.getElementById("main-wrapper").innerHTML = getData.template_code;
</script>
```

How can I do the same in Angular 2, I have a component `webview.component.html` and `webview.component.ts`?

Comment: you can include the script block in your webview.component.html

Comment: can you guide how ? with an example

Comment: This is reported below to be a reasonable duplicate: [How to inject Document in service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521298/how-to-inject-document-in-service)

Answer (score 2):

You can import document object inside your angular component in this way:

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

So you use it:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any) {
      document.write(getData.template_code);
  }
}
```

There is a pretty similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521298/how-to-inject-document-in-angular-2-service).

Comment: this solution looks like of angular 1 , i need a solution for angular 2

Comment: @user2828442 then tag your question with Angular 2's `angular` tag, not `angularjs`

Comment: @user2828442: This is an Angular 2+ solution. Angular 1 doesn't have annotations, or the `@angular` package namespace.