# How to call a function of component from template of another component in ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I want to call a function of component from template of another component in

ionic 2.I get a dashboard in in my app **dashboard.html** using home.ts

component.

```
<ion-content> 
<div class="dashboardSection">

            <a href="" (click)="fetchAllClass()">
                <div class="header padding text-center classes common">
                    <img src="assets/images/icos_15.png" alt="Your logo here"  width="50%" height="auto"/>
                    <p class="Sectiontitle">STUDENTS</p>
                </div>
            </a></div>
</ion-content>
```

this is showing with the help of home.ts

```
doLogin(event) {    
    var user1 =this.loginForm.value;
    var password = this.loginForm.controls.password.value;
    this.homeService.doLogin(user1).subscribe(
        user =>{
            this.user = user.results; 
            this.storage.set('isLoggedIn', 'shahjad');
            this.navCtrl.setRoot(DashboardComponent, {thing1: user });
        },
        err => {
            console.log(err);
        },
        () => console.log('login complete')

        );
}
```

Now, I want to call student component'function from dashboard Component

I created student component like **students.ts**

```
@Component({

    selector: 'page-students',
    templateUrl: "./students.html"
})
export class StudentsComponent {
    dashboardItem: any;
    mode = "Observable";
    errorMessage: string;

    constructor(public fb: FormBuilder,private studentsService: StudentsService,public navCtrl: NavController,private storage: Storage,private menu: MenuController) {}

    fetchAllClass(event) {  

        alert("fd");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If your studentcomponent is a direct child of dashboard you can use a viewchild.

```
<page-student #student></page-student>
```

In you component:

```
@ViewChild('student') student: StudentComponent
```

Answer (score 2):

- First, the best way to create a function and use in many component is use [service](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular2/angular2_services.htm).
- Second, if you still want to call a function in other component, you can do like that:

Step1: Inject your `StudentComponent` in `DashboardComponent`:

```
import { Component,Inject,forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import {StudentComponent} from '../component/students'
@Component({
   selector: 'dashboard',
   templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
   providers:[StudentComponent]
})
constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => StudentComponent))private studentComponent: StudentComponent){
}
```

Step2: Now you can call StudentComponent's function:

```
fetchAllClass(event) {  
this.studentComponent.fetchAllClass(event);
}
```

Step3: You can call new `fetchAllClass` function in template:

```
<a href="" (click)="fetchAllClass()">
```

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should take a look at Angular's services and [how to build a custom one](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-build-an-angular-2-service--cms-27943).
You can see a [thread about this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521298/how-to-inject-document-in-angular-2-service).

Basically, you will create an Injectable, add it to your NgModule (or a shred module) and then inject then in the components you need to use it.
Other great [tutorial](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/di/angular2/inject_and_injectable.html) is here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a provider and put all the functions that fetches data in there. This way you can easily import the provider and get the data wherever you want.

For more, refer [this post](https://www.joshmorony.com/how-why-and-when-to-use-providers-in-ionic-2/)