# unlink stylesheet loaded in angular 4

Tags: angular

I have this function to load stylesheet based on user's choice 'en' or 'ar':

```
addStyleSheet(lang: string) {
        let headID = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        let link = document.createElement('link');
        link.type = 'text/css';
        link.rel = 'stylesheet';
        link.id = 'widget_styles';link.type = 'text/css';


        headID.appendChild(link);
        if (lang == "ar") {
            link.href = AppGlobals.APP_URL + './assets/css/bootstrap-rtl.css';
        }
        else if (lang == "en") {
            link.href = AppGlobals.APP_URL + './assets/css/bootstrap.css';
        }
    }
```

My default language is English so the first page is working fine, also the first 'ar' choice fine and success to load 'bootstrap-rtl', but when I press 'en' again, the 'bootstrap-rtl' is already loaded so the design crash, I tried to unlink the css file using `removeChild` but it doesn't work fine, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Disable the CSS element on function call**

constructor(private myElement: ElementRef, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) {

```
}
addStyleSheet() {
        this.document.getElementById('eng-css').disabled = false;
        this.document.getElementById('otherlang-css').disabled = true;
    }
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="eng-css" type="text/css" href="css/start.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" id="otherlang-css" type="text/css" href="css/app.min.css" />
```

Comment: I got this error
ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'disabled' of null.
I'm sure that the id is exist

Comment: what about "this.document" ?     be sure to inject document into your constructor of Component  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521298/how-to-inject-document-in-angular-2-service

Comment: import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';                                                                    @Component({
    templateUrl: '  '
})                                                                                                         export class YourComponent{                                                                                                                               constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document)                                {}
}