# Angular 6 to cant add java script correctly

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

Im used my university ty project for `angular6` and `ng bootstrap`and Im try to implement this [Sidenav](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav)  for my project but its cant  do add correctly .any one know how to add correctly  my project

**facilitistatus.component.html**

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" (click)="open(closeNav)">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<h2>Animated Sidenav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu.</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" (click)="open(openNav)">&#9776; open</span>
```

**facilitistatus.component.ts**

```
 open(openNav) {
    document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width = '250px';
  }

  open(closeNav) {
    document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width = '0';
  }
```

**facilitistatus.component.css**

```
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

**I got the following error**

> ERROR in src/app/facilitistatus/facilitistatus.component.ts(33,11):
>   error TS2393: Duplicate function implementation.
>   src/app/facilitistatus/facilitistatus.component.ts(44,3): error
>   TS2393: Duplicate function implementation.
>   src/app/facilitistatus/facilitistatus.component.ts(50,3): error
>   TS2393: Duplicate function implementation.
>   src/app/facilitistatus/facilitistatus.component.ts(61,11): error
>   TS2393: Duplicate function implementation.
>   src/app/facilitistatus/facilitistatus.component.ts(75,5): error
>   TS2393: Duplicate function implementation.
>   src/app/facilitistatus/facilitistatus.component.ts(79,3): error
>   TS2393: Duplicate function implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message spells it out: duplicate function. Javascript does not have function overloading. Instead, your methods need different names.

```
openNav() {
  document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width = '250px';
}

closeNav() {
  document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width = '0';
}
```

Comment: Hi Madam,  I added your code , but  side menu is not open ;(

Comment: Opening the side menu sounds like a separate issue.

Comment: Madam, i dded your code but i got a this error ERROR in src/app/facilitistatus/facilitistatus.component.ts(33,11): error TS2393: Duplicate function implementation.
src/app/facilitistatus/facilitistatus.component.ts(44,3): error TS2393: Duplicate function implementation.
src/app/facilitistatus/facilitistatus.component.ts(50,3): error TS2393: Duplicate function implementation.
src/app/facilitistatus/facilitistatus.component.ts(61,11): error TS2393: Duplicate function implementation.

Comment: Are there other duplicate functions? Lines 33, 44, 50, and 61?

Comment: Sorry that is my issue. now error is fixed but side nav not open

Answer (score 0):

As i can see in **src/app/facilitistatus/facilitistatus.component.ts**

```
**open(openNav)** {
    document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width = '250px';
  }

  **open(closeNav)** {
    document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width = '0';
  }
```

**Modification needed

1) Rename methods to

```
**openNav()** {
    document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width = '250px';
  }

  **closeNav()** {
    document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width = '0';
  }
```

the use similar in .html binding.

2) Use DOCUMENT from @angular/common as a service and then play with javascript.
    Refer Link for DOCUMENT adding

> [[How to inject Document in Angular 2 service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521298/how-to-inject-document-in-angular-2-service?rq=1)
>   ]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of resizing div's width from 0 to 250px, you should try keeping the width 250px, and when in closed mode give it a `transform:transalteX(-250px)`, and in open mode, provide it `translateX(0)`
In both open and close case provide add a different class to identify the mode.

```
// By Default, close mode
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
    transform : translateX(-250px);
}

// Open mode
.sidenav.open {
    transform : translateX(0);
}
```

This was for opening and closing side-nav, and yes method overloading issue has been resolved in other answers. And use this handleNav method with boolean variable

```
handleNav(isOpen: boolean) {
  document.getElementById('mySidenav').classList.remove('open');
  if(isOpen)
  document.getElementById('mySidenav').classList.add('open');
}
```