# Mocking DOCUMENT in Angular/Karma

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

How do you mock DOCUMENT (the shadow representation of an HTMLDocument) in Angular? The implementation is using this in the constructor:

```
@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document
```

After looking at this [How to inject Document in Angular 2 service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521298/how-to-inject-document-in-angular-2-service) I have put this in my .spec setup:

```
const lazyPath = 'dummy';
const pathname = `/${lazyPath}`;
const document = { location: { pathname } as Location } as Document;
beforeEachProviders(() => ([ {provide: DOCUMENT, useValue: document} ]));
```

But it's giving me errors:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/main/components/app-lazy/app-lazy.component.spec.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core/testing/src/testing_internal' in '...'
resolve '@angular/core/testing/src/testing_internal' in '....'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: .../package.json (relative path: ...)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
```

When I use a simple providers: [] in TestBed.configureTestingModule instead of beforeEachProviders from the testing_internal package, the component is undefined, eg not initialized properly. It only initializes in unit tests  (in the non-test execution both works) when I switch from an injected document, to the window object (on which I cannot set/mock location). What can I do?

Comment: Moved my comment to an answer to help with the formatting.

Answer (score 7):

You should avoid mocking the entire document object and mock/spy individual methods/properties on it instead.

Assuming you have the following in your component/service:

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
...
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}
```

You can test against the document object by injecting it inside your `beforeEach`

```
describe('SomeComponent', () => {
  let component: SomeComponent;
  let doc: Document;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [SomeComponent],
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ]
    });
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    doc = TestBed.inject(DOCUMENT); // Inject here **************
  });


  it('set document title', () => {
    component.setPageTitle('foobar'); // Assuming this component method is `this.document.title = title`
    expect(doc.title).toBe('foobar');
  });

  it('calls querySelectorAll', () => {
    const spy = spyOn(doc, 'querySelectorAll');
    component.someMethodThatQueries();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 6):

I experience most likely a similar issue as @Phil. It appears that the problem is related to injecting DOCUMENT into a component.

When you mock the injected DOCUMENT, then the call on `TestBed.createComponent()` throws an error when internally calling `document.querySelectorAll()`.

`TestBed.createComponent()` appears to be accessing the injected mocked document object. Not sure if this is a bug or intended.

I experience the issue with Angular 11 recently. Because I was too lazy to set up a new stackblitz, I reproduced it on an existing stackblitz based on Angular 8. But issue is the same there.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/jasmine-in-angular-beomut?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.spec.ts

**My current solution/workaround for this issue is:**

Move the logic related to `document`into a service. There it can be tested easily without calling `TestBed.createComponent()`. In your component you can then mock the service.

Comment: I worked around it by mocking `querySelectorAll` in my `mockDocument`.

`const mockDocument = { location: new Location(), querySelectorAll: jest.fn };`

`TestBed.configureTestingModule({  providers: [{ provide: DOCUMENT, useValue: mockDocument }] });`

Comment: @ArcadeRenegade I tried this way but its not working

Comment: I am getting below error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at <Jasmine>
    at DOMTestComponentRenderer.insertRootElement (https://jasmine-in-angular-beomut.stackblitz.io/turbo_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@8.1.0/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js:78:42)
    at TestBedViewEngine.createComponent (https://jasmine-in-angular-beomut.stackblitz.io/turbo_modules/@angular/core@8.1.0/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:2630:35)
    at Function.TestBedViewEngine.createComponen

Comment: Looks like this behavior is indented. Please see these github issues: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/45031 and https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/45278

Answer (score 3):

Posting this as an answer because the formatting doesn't work in a comment.

Could you share a stackblitz if possible? When I need to inject a mock, I usually set it up like:

```js
  // ... beginning of file

  const mockDocument = { location: { pathname } };

  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [...],
    // Provide DOCUMENT Mock 
    providers: [
      { provide: DOCUMENT, useValue: mockDocument }
    ]
  }));

  // ...rest of file
```

Comment: Are you sure this should work? My app is a bit complex, but the part about changing window to (the injected) document is what makes tests pass or fail (with TypeError: el.querySelectorAll is not a function). Your solution is the one I have used originally and this is the error I was getting.

Comment: Could you post a minimum stackblitz? I haven't used DOCUMENT in a while so I may be a touch rusty.

Comment: @HumbertoMorera could you elaborate a little bit more? If you need to share snippets of your code, you could open a new question and link to it. I'll take a look when I have time.

Answer (score 3):

If you provide alias `DOCUMENT` in your `app.module.ts` as follows:

```
import { DOCUMENT } from "@angular/common";

...

providers: [
    { provide: Document, useExisting: DOCUMENT }
]
```

You can inject it casually like this:

```
export class Component {
    constructor (private document: Document) {
       document.getElementById("button")
    }
}
```

And you can even mock it easily:

```
class MockDocument {}

describe('MostAwesomeComponent', () => {
    let component: Component;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<Component>;
  
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ Component ],
            providers: [{ provide: Document, useClass: MockDocument}]
        })
        .compileComponents();
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Thanks to **Ernestas Buta** - [source](https://mounted.dev/snippets/how-to-inject-document-in-angular/)

Comment: Couldn't provide it "casualy",
go this error when I tried to inject it like so to my component:
 Could not resolve type Document.

Comment: Angular 15 and working perfectly!