# Accessing functions of angular in javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, angular-material

Pretty novice in coding, so I have no clue which language it is.
I have a component.ts file which contains a function. In ngOnInit(), I have written a part of code in Js cause of dependency. Im trying to access the function written outside ngOnInit(), in this js block.

Tried accessing the function using this.openDialog(), but that just showed error saying its not defined.

Tried defining the function itself in js by creating an object of the component and trying to call the function,

```
constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, private datePipe: DatePipe) {

  }
ngOnInit(){
var testVar = new testComponent(dia, date);
//dia, date are respective constructor params
}
```

Pretty sure thats not proper, but tried it.

Component.ts:

```
export class test implements OnInit{
openDialog(){
//this is mat angular dialog
}
ngOnInit(){

 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

// trying to call the above openDialog here. 
});
}

}
```

Trying to call the dialog inside document.addEventListener();
Converting `document.addEventListener();` is not an option. 
It would help if I can call that dialog inside.

**Edit 1**
Sharing more code, for info:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      var events = []

      var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

      var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
        eventLimit: true, // for all non-TimeGrid views
        views: {
          dayGridMonth: {
            eventLimit: 5 // adjust to 6 only for timeGridWeek/timeGridDay
          }
        },
        themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
        businessHours: {
          daysOfWeek: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
          startTime: '00:00',
          endTime: '24:00',
        },
        header: {
          left: 'prev,next',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'dayGridMonth,listView,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        },
        plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, listPlugin, bootstrapPlugin, timeGrigPlugin],
        eventOverlap: false,
        displayEventTime: false,
        eventClick: function (info) {
          this.curEvnt = info;
          console.log(this.curEvnt)
          this.openDialog(info.event);   //ERROR

        }
      });
    calendar.render();
});
```

Open dialog is defined and can be called in onInit, but im trying to implement the above code
Error: `this.openDialog is not a function`

Comment: You can just call your class functions by using `this.`

Comment: ```TypeError: this.openDialog is not a function``` using this.

Comment: Remove the `document.addEventListener....` nonsense.

Comment: Please check the updated question

Comment: Only this part of the code is not in angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use from `Lifecycle Hooks` in angular.
After creating a component/directive by calling its constructor, Angular calls the `lifecycle hook` methods in the following sequence at specific moments:

```
ngOnChanges()
ngOnInit()
ngDoCheck()
ngAfterContentInit()
ngAfterContentChecked()
ngAfterViewInit()
ngAfterViewChecked()
ngOnDestroy()
```

please reference to angular doc : [Lifecycle Hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

```
class MyComponent implements AfterContentInit {
    openDialog(){
        //this is mat angular dialog
    }

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        this.openDialog()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I think you might have misunderstood my question, Im trying to call an angular function inside that Document.addEventListener function. Which is giving me ```TypeError: this.openDialog is not a function``` error. The function isnt recognized.

Comment: if you want access to `document` in angular must be inject document in `cunstractor`. please check this : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521298/how-to-inject-document-in-angular-2-service)

Comment: It is better to use `Lifecycle Hooks`

Comment: and check this: [How do I include a JavaScript script file in Angular and call a function from that script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44817349/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-script-file-in-angular-and-call-a-function-from-th)

Comment: Thank you. Will get back if there are issues