# Cannot set Header Cookie in Angular even when passing withCredentials: true

Tags: javascript, angular, http, cors, http-headers

### Problem

I am trying to set a header named Cookie. I do this using an interceptor, so that it gets done on every request.

### Code

```
@Injectable
export class HeaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private: authService: AuthenticationService) {}

  intercept(reg: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  return from(this.authService.getAuthentication()).pipe(
    switchMap((token) => {
      const headers = req.headers
        .set(TOKEN, "someToken")
        .set("Cookie", "someCookie")
        .append("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .append("Accept", "application/json");

      const requestClone = req.clone({ headers, withCredentials: true });
      return next.handle(requestClone);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

### What happens

I always get:

> Attempt to set a forbidden header was denied: Cookie

So what can I do here? I also tried setting `withCredentials: true` directly on every request which also did not work. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some headers are forbidden to be used programmatically for security concerns and to ensure that the user agent remains in full control over them.

**Cookie** is one of the forbidden header among the list of [Forbidden header name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name) list, and hence you cannot set it within the HTTP request header directly from the code.

From [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name):

> A forbidden header name is the name of any HTTP header that cannot be modified programmatically; specifically, an HTTP request header name

**Spec:** https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name

You can always set the cookies via [document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#write_a_new_cookie) and browser will automatically send the cookies that matches the criteria. Trying to set cookies to foreign domain will be silently ignored.

Angular comes up with a [DOCUMENT](https://angular.io/api/common/DOCUMENT) DI token which can be used to inject document in a service. You can read more about it [how-to-inject-document-in-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521298/how-to-inject-document-in-service).

Comment: I tried setting it via `document.cookie` and that seemed to have worked as when I enter that into the browser console. I can only see the name though there, I guess out of security reasons there is no way to see the value, or? Also, can I somehow see the cookie sent on the request? Or is this also not possible?

Comment: You can check the cookies stored in browser as well as those sent within your Browser dev tools. [Check cookies in Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/storage/cookies/) and [Check headers in Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/#details). Similar way in other browsers too, you should be able to view them.